# Computing the Laplacian in Polar Coordinates

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, polar-coordinates

Similar questions have been asked on this site but none of them seemed to help me. I'm asked to compute the Laplacian $$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}$$ in terms of polar coordinates.

I did do it, but I don't understand why what I did is correct, and I don't understand the more "brute force" way to do it at all.

Here is what I did:

> I calculated $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}$ in terms of $r,$ $\theta,$ $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}.$ This gave me a system of linear equations which I wrote as
>   $$\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial}{\partial r} \\\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta & \sin\theta \\\ -r\sin\theta & r\cos\theta \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \\\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\end{pmatrix}.$$
>   I inverted to get $$\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \\\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\end{pmatrix} = \frac{1}{r}\begin{pmatrix}r\cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\\ r\sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial}{\partial r} \\\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\end{pmatrix},$$
>   and then I simply wrote \begin{align}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)\\ &= \left(\cos\theta \frac{\partial}{\partial r}-\frac{1}{r}\sin\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\right)\left(\cos\theta \frac{\partial}{\partial r}-\frac{1}{r}\sin\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\right)\\ &= \cos\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(\cos\theta \frac{\partial}{\partial r}-\frac{1}{r}\sin\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\right) -\frac{1}{r}\sin\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\left(\cos\theta \frac{\partial}{\partial r}-\frac{1}{r}\sin\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\right)\\ &= \cos^2\theta \frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2} - \frac{2}{r}\sin\theta\cos\theta\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r
> \partial\theta} +\frac{1}{r^2}\sin^2\theta\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta^2}.\end{align}
>   I similarly got $$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} = \sin^2\theta \frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2} + \frac{2}{r}\sin\theta\cos\theta\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r
> \partial\theta} +\frac{1}{r^2}\cos^2\theta\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta^2}.$$ Adding the two yields $$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2}+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta^2},$$
>   which Spivak says is correct.

Explicitly, here are my questions:

1. In my solution, when I found $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2},$ I simply "multiplied" the expressions in the second line of the large aligned equation (treating multiplication of the partial operators as composition). Why am I allowed to do this? Why does the expression on the left not *act* on the thing on the right, forcing me to do the product rule and other nonsense to get the answer?
2. My original idea was just to compute the Laplacian using the chain rule. That is, write $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial}{\partial r} \frac{\partial r}{\partial x}$ and compute $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}$ from there. My problem with this is that I keep getting confused about in which variables I should be writing everything, and how the partial derivative operators act on these other expressions. For example, I compute $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial}{\partial r} \frac{\partial r}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\frac{\partial}{\partial r} - \frac{y}{x^2+y^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta},$ but then I don't know where to go. Help understanding this method would be greatly appreciated.

If anything is unclear let me know and I'll make the necessary edits.

Comment: Isn't there supposed to be a 1/r*d/dr term in the final answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I simply "multiplied"

Imagine a function $f(x, y) = f(x(r,\theta),y(r,\theta)) = f(r,\theta)$, you just found

$$
\frac{\partial f(x, y)}{\partial x} = \cos\theta \frac{\partial f(r,\theta)}{\partial r} - \frac{1}{r}\sin\theta \frac{\partial f(r,\theta)}{\partial \theta} \equiv h
$$

Then apply it again

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial^2 f(x, y)}{\partial x^2} &=&\frac{\partial h}{\partial x} \\
&=& \cos\theta \frac{\partial h(r,\theta)}{\partial r} - \frac{1}{r}\sin\theta \frac{\partial h(r,\theta)}{\partial \theta}  \\
&=& \cos\theta \frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left[\cos\theta \frac{\partial f(r,\theta)}{\partial r} - \frac{1}{r}\sin\theta \frac{\partial f(r,\theta)}{\partial \theta}\right] - \frac{1}{r}\sin\theta\left[\cos\theta \frac{\partial f(r,\theta)}{\partial r} - \frac{1}{r}\sin\theta \frac{\partial f(r,\theta)}{\partial \theta} \right]
\end{eqnarray}

That when you think about it is the same thing you did. So actually multiplying is the right way of doing it. In general this is true for any operator, if $T$ is an operator then

$$
T^2f = T(Tf)
$$

> My original idea was just to compute the Laplacian using the chain rule

It is completely equivalent to what you did in the first step. Here's the first term

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &=& \frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial r} + \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} \\
&=& \frac{x}{r}\frac{\partial f}{\partial r} - \frac{y}{r^2}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} \\
&=& \cos\theta \frac{\partial f}{\partial r} - \frac{\sin\theta}{r}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}
\end{eqnarray}

and now apply the same logic as before

Comment: I may have been unclear so I'll write this with a simpler example. Why is it that $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)=x\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}$ and not $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+x\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}?$ This is where my confusion about my solution lies.

Comment: Also, in the final aligned equation, did you really mean to write $\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}=\frac{r}{x}?$

Comment: @D.Brogan Nope, it was a typo $r/x$ (already fixed it). As for the question, it is the second one, why do you think it is the first one?

Comment: When applying $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ to $-\frac{1}{r}\sin\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta},$ what I did was I ignored the $\frac{1}{r},$ obtaining $-\frac{1}{r}\sin\theta\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta\partial r}.$ I would think that I would get $\frac{1}{r^2}\sin\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}-\frac{1}{r}\sin\theta\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta\partial r}.$ Why do I get the first and not the second?

Comment: This answer is not correct. When you apply the derivative for the second time, you need to take into account the Leibniz product rule, so that you also get some **first** order terms. So the expressions for the second derivatives in the question are wrong, you do **not** just “multiply”. The correct expression for $\partial^2 / \partial x^2$ is given [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/585981/1242).

Comment: @D.Brogan I see, I just realize that you're missing terms in your last line for the expression $\partial^2f/\partial x^2$, indeed you need to use the second form in your comment above for both $\partial/\partial r$ and $\partial/\partial \theta$. The thing is that most terms are going to cancel after you add them together

Comment: So I just got lucky in that I did the computation incorrectly but everything worked out anyway. Got it. Everything makes sense now. Thank you!