# Double partial derivative proof

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Let $z=f(x,y)$  where $x:=r \cos \theta$ and $y := r \sin \theta$.
I had to prove that $\frac {\partial ^{2}z}{\partial \ x^{2}} + \frac {\partial ^{2}z}{\partial \ x^{2}} = \frac {\partial ^{2}z}{\partial \ r^{2}} \ + \dots$ The whole equation was given.

My doubt:

I applied Jacobian and tried to solve this but I ended up in a loop where I was substituting the same things back and forth.

The solution provided said this.

$\frac {\partial ^{2}z}{\partial r^{2}} \ = \frac {\partial}{\partial r}(\frac {\partial z}{\partial r})  = \frac {\partial}{\partial r}(\cos \theta \frac {\partial z}{\partial x} + \sin \theta \frac {\partial z}{\partial y})$

$ = \cos \theta \ [ \cos \theta \frac {\partial}{\partial x} + \sin \theta \frac {\partial }{\partial y} ](\frac {\partial z}{\partial x}) \ + \sin \theta [ \cos \theta \frac {\partial }{\partial x} + \sin \theta \frac {\partial }{\partial y} ] (\frac {\partial z}{\partial y}).$

I do not understand the last step. What exactly is happening? Why do we use the partial derivative of $z$ with respect to $r$ (and skip the $z$ in the numerator) and multiply it with partial derivative of z with respect to $x$ and $y$? Since $x$ and $y$ are functions of $r$ and $\theta$ and since in $\frac {\partial z}{\partial x}$ we have kept $y$ constant are we accounting for that? I am really confused as this relevant theory wasn't taught in class and the professor hasn't been helpful to clear this part. Any insight is highly appreciated.

Comment: Does this help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548715/computing-second-partial-derivative-with-polar-coordinates/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we look at first at the *general situation* and develop the second partial derivative by consequently applying the *[chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule)*. This way we can better see  symmetries which is helpful when calculating the special case.

We consider the functions
\begin{align*}
z=f(x,y)\qquad\qquad x&=x(r,\theta)=r\cos\theta\\
y&=y(r,\theta)=r\sin\theta
\end{align*}

**First partial derivative:**$\quad\Large{\frac{\partial z}{\partial r}}$

> We obtain by applying the chain rule
> \begin{align*}
> \frac{\partial z}{\partial r}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\cdot\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}
> +\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\cdot \frac{\partial y}{\partial r}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

**Second partial derivative:**$\quad\Large{\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial r^2}}$

> We obtain by applying $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ to (1) using the chain rule again as well as the *[product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule)* of derivatives
> \begin{align*}
> \frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial r^2}
> &=\frac{\partial }{\partial r}
> \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\cdot\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}
> +\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\cdot \frac{\partial y}{\partial r}\right)\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{\partial }{\partial r}
> \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\cdot\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}\right)
> +\frac{\partial }{\partial r}\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\cdot \frac{\partial y}{\partial r}\right)\tag{3}\\
> &=\color{red}{\frac{\partial }{\partial r}\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)}\cdot\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}
> +\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\cdot\frac{\partial }{\partial r}\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}\right)\\
> &\qquad+\color{blue}{\frac{\partial }{\partial r}\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)}\cdot\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}
> +\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\cdot\frac{\partial }{\partial r}\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}\right)\tag{4}\\
> &=\color{red}{\left(\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2}\cdot\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}
> +\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y\partial x}\cdot \frac{\partial y}{\partial r}\right)}\cdot\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}
> +\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\cdot\frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial r^2}\\
> &\qquad+\color{blue}{\left(\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x\partial y}\cdot\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}
> +\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y^2}\cdot \frac{\partial y}{\partial r}\right)}\cdot\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}
> +\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\cdot\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial r^2}\tag{5}\\
> &=\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2}\cdot\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}\right)^2
> +\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y\partial x}\cdot \frac{\partial x}{\partial r}\cdot\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}
> +\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\cdot\frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial r^2}\\
> &\qquad\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y^2}\cdot \left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}\right)^2
> +\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x\partial y}\cdot\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}
> \cdot\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}
> +\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\cdot\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial r^2}\tag{6}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:* This is due to presentation issues a rather lengthy calculation. Usually we might skip (3) and (4) and obtain (5) directly from (2).

- In (2) we apply the chain rule as we did in (1)
- In (3) we use the linearity of the differential operator
- In (4) we apply  the product rule
- In (5) we apply the chain rule again
- In (6) we multiply out and do a few rearrangements

**Special case: $x(r,\theta)=r\cos \theta,\ y(r,\theta)=r\sin \theta$**

> The partial derivatives of the special case give
> \begin{align*}
> &x(r,\theta)=r\cos \theta&&\frac{\partial}{\partial r}x(r,\theta)=\cos \theta&&\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2}x(r,\theta)=0\\
> &y(r,\theta)=r\sin \theta&&\frac{\partial}{\partial r}y(r,\theta)=\sin \theta&&\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2}y(r,\theta)=0
> \end{align*}
> Putting these results in (6) we finally obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial r^2}}&\color{blue}{f(x(r,\theta),y(r,v\theta))}=\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial r^2}f(r\cos \theta,r\sin \theta)\\
> &=\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2}\cdot \cos^2\theta
> +\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y\partial x}\cdot \cos \theta\cdot\sin\theta
> +\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\cdot 0\\
> &\qquad+\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y^2}\cdot \sin^2 \theta
> +\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x\partial y}\cdot \cos\theta\cdot\sin\theta
> +\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\cdot0\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2}\cdot\cos^2\theta
> +\left(\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y\partial x}+\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x\partial y}\right)\cdot\cos \theta\cdot\sin\theta
> +\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y^2}\cdot\sin^2 \theta}\tag{7}
> \end{align*}
> in accordance with OPs formula.

Comment: Thank you. This was extremely informative and my doubt has been cleared quite well. I know i am not supposed to use the comment to give thanks but this answer was really helpful to me.

Comment: @ShauryaGoyal: Many thanks for your nice comment. Good to see, the answer is useful! :-)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your question is really why
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial r} = \cos(\theta) \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \sin(\theta) \frac{\partial}{\partial y} $$
since this is what is being used in the last step.

**The short answer:** the chain rule

**The long answer:** $x$ and $y$ can be written as functions of $r$ and $\theta$, as you've written at the very top of your post. Then a function $f(x,y)$ can be thought of as $f\Big(x(r,\theta), \; y(r,\theta)\Big)$. Then the chain rule says that
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial r} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial r} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial r} $$
You get the result by seeing that $\frac{\partial x}{\partial r} = \cos(\theta)$ and $\frac{\partial y}{\partial r} = \sin(\theta)$.