# Partial derivative $\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x^2}$ of function $F$ expressed in polar coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, polar-coordinates

This is from *Mathematical Methods in the Physical Sciences*, Mary L. Boas 3rd edition, Chapter 4, section 11, page 240. During a derivation of the Laplace equation in polar coordinates using abbreviations such as $G = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}$ and $H = \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}$ and the substituting it in and taking its partial derivative, I do not see how we do not have to apply the product rule. So getting to the exact part which confuses me, we have,

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial r} \frac{\partial r}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial \theta} \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}= \cos(\theta) \frac{\partial F}{\partial r} - \frac{\sin(\theta)}{r}\frac{\partial F}{\partial \theta}$$

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial r} \frac{\partial r}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial \theta} \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial y}= \sin(\theta) \frac{\partial F}{\partial r} + \frac{\cos(\theta)}{r}\frac{\partial F}{\partial \theta}$$

Then we let $G = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}$ and $H = \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}$ thus,

$$G = \cos(\theta) \frac{\partial F}{\partial r} - \frac{\sin(\theta)}{r}\frac{\partial F}{\partial \theta}$$
$$H = \sin(\theta) \frac{\partial F}{\partial r} + \frac{\cos(\theta)}{r}\frac{\partial F}{\partial \theta}$$

This is the part where I become confused on, which is simply letting,

$$\frac{\partial G}{\partial x} = \cos(\theta) \frac{\partial G}{\partial r} - \frac{\sin(\theta)}{r}\frac{\partial G}{\partial \theta} \tag{3}$$

$$\frac{\partial H}{\partial y} = \sin(\theta) \frac{\partial H}{\partial r} + \frac{\cos(\theta)}{r}\frac{\partial H}{\partial \theta} \tag{4}$$

So this is the part that confuses me, as for example $\frac{\partial G}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x^2} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(\cos(\theta) \frac{\partial F}{\partial r} - \frac{\sin(\theta)}{r}\frac{\partial F}{\partial \theta} \right)$. $\cos(\theta)$ can be represented as a function of x such as $\frac{x}{r}$ So how can we just bypass differentiating these parts by simply replacing it with G and then getting equations 3 and 4? I am new to manipulating derivatives in this manner and I am currently teaching myself, any help would be great! Thank you again!

Comment: This is from Mathematical Methods in the Physical Sciences Mary L. Boas 3rd edition. Chapter 4 section 11 page 240. I may have, I tried to include as much as I could. If there’s anything you think I forgot please let me know and I will find the answer and share here. Very sorry.

Comment: I didn't look up the book but maybe someone will do. Nevertheless, you might find [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/548715/418542) interesting

Comment: It all follows from your original equations: $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=\cos(\theta)\frac{\partial F}{\partial r}-\frac{\sin(\theta)}{r}\frac{\partial F}{\partial \theta}$ and similar for $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}$. The point is that this relation is true for _any_ function $F\equiv F(x,y) = F(\,x(r,\theta),\, y(r,\theta)\,)$ and $G$ just happens to be a function of this form, so we may use the same identity. You are correct in that we _could_ expand $\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}$ in terms of $F$, if you wish.