# What does it mean for an equation to "become" another under a change of coordinates?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I am not asking about the symbolic calculations, but about the interpretation. The exercise is:

> Show that under the transformation $x = r \cos \theta$, $y = r \sin \theta$, the equation $$\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2V}{\partial y^2} = 0 \tag 1$$
> becomes
> $$\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial r^2} + \frac 1r \frac {\partial V}{\partial \theta} + \frac {1}{r^2} \frac {\partial^2 V}{\partial \theta^2} = 0. \tag 2$$

What does it mean for $(1)$ to become $(2)$? Am I just supposed to calculate each component in $(2)$, add them up, and show that the sum is $0$, assuming that $(1)$ holds? If this is the case, I don't see how this could be called equation $(1)$ "becoming" equation $(2).$

Comment: The chain rule is what you need.

Comment: @SeanRoberson I am aware. I can calculate the LHS of $(2)$, and using $(1)$, show that it equals zero. But why is this called equation $(1)$ "becoming" equation $2$? Presumably there are infinitely many equations $(2')$ you can prove in this manner.

Comment: You're essentially expressing one coordinate system in terms of a another: from Cartesian $(x,y)$ to polar $(r,\theta)$. The equation for a function in one coordinate system thus needs to be modified accordingly -- so a function $V(x,y)$ is Cartesian is only equal to $V(r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta)$. But clearly this latter function could, somehow, be reduced to just the form $V(r,\theta)$. However, that change in the variables in turn causes a change in the derivative and other behaviors; hence, the PDE you satisfy in $(1)$ will look different, and give rise to $(2)$.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer Right. And once we've got $V(r, \theta)$, we would have partials with respect to $r$ and $\theta$ instead of $x$ and $y$. And I can calculate the LHS of $(2)$ and show it equals $0$, using $(1)$. But how would you discover $(2)$ if it wasn't given to you?

Comment: @Tobi: You can go from (1) to (2) like this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548715/computing-second-partial-derivative-with-polar-coordinates